# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I ran pip install pyaudio in my terminal and got this error:

> Command "/home/oliver/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-ub9alt7s/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-e9_md34a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ub9alt7s/pyaudio/

So I ran sudo apt-install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio

which seemed to work.

Then in jupyter:
import pyaudio

error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

Can anyone help me work out this problem? I am not familiar with Ubuntu and it's commands paths etc as I've only been using it a few months.

If you need more information, let me know what, and how. Thanks

Comment: Are you running your code inside of a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, inside Oracle VM Virtual Box

Comment: Can you do which python to confirm that the directory where you have installed is the same as the one from which you are trying to pick the package.

Comment: Also, check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/798455/importerror-no-module-named-pyaudio-despite-python-pyaudio-installed

Comment: >which python
/home/oliver/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: Thanks for the link, unless I misunderstand though, the path is the same, and nothing else should be conflicting as the script only has one command "import pyaudio"

Comment: @Oli_WH Ah, no, sorry, I meant a [Python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). If you are using Anaconda you kinda are, packages installed with `apt-get` will not be available within the Anaconda environment. Try to run `conda install -c anaconda pyaudio `.

Comment: @jdehesa Under Johny Vaknin's answer I found my fix. portaudio19-dev and python-all-dev where two packages I didn't have which were needed for the pip install. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the documentation of pyaudio if it is compatible with your python version
Some modules which are not compatible may be installed without issues,
 yet still won't work when trying to access them

Comment: "Debian/Ubuntu

Notes:
Be sure to install the portaudio library development package (portaudio19-dev) and the python development package (python-all-dev) beforehand." -- https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/ --


sudo apt get-install python-all-dev
sudo apt get-install portaudio19-dev
followed by pip install pyaudio has fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue, and my solution was ...

```
python3 playmusic.py
```

I didn't use the preinstalled MAC's python.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows then these command on the terminal:

`pip install pipwin`

`pipwin install pyaudio`